# load cocos2dx(3.0 beta) project for android on adt with error (on osx)

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have developed an small game for cross-platform, it works well on on ios and web

but when I try to load project for android on adt, it reports error (on osx)

```
!SESSION 2014-06-25 22:19:12.645 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -keyring /Users/zhengwang/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -keyring /Users/zhengwang/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-06-25 22:19:44.594
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 4 2014-06-25 22:33:59.725
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while saving project preferences: /gongzhu/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: A resource already exists on disk '/Users/zhengwang/cd-standard/cocos2d-js-v3.0-beta/gongzhu/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/.settings'.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.assertCreateRequirements(Folder.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.create(Folder.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences$1.run(ProjectPreferences.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.save(ProjectPreferences.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalFlush(EclipsePreferences.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.flush(ProjectPreferences.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setOption(JavaProject.java:2954)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.checkAndFixCompilerCompliance(ProjectHelper.java:513)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.fixProjectClasspathEntries(ProjectHelper.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.fixProject(ProjectHelper.java:296)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createEclipseProject(NewProjectCreator.java:837)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createProjectAsync(NewProjectCreator.java:660)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.access$0(NewProjectCreator.java:590)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator$3.execute(NewProjectCreator.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 272 2014-06-25 22:33:59.744
!MESSAGE A resource already exists on disk '/Users/mymac/cd-standard/cocos2d-js-v3.0-beta/gongzhu/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/.settings'.
```

and screenshot

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: Did you read the error? "!MESSAGE A resource already exists on disk '/Users/mymac/cd-standard/cocos2d-js-v3.0-beta/gongzhu/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/.settings'"

Comment: I removed it, but reports the error again

Answer (score 0):

Approach below worked for me:

1. Delete `.settings` folder or `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file in
   this folder.
2. Restart eclipse
3. If the errors in your project persists you need to find each class
   with errors and import correct auto-generated `R` class.